# OpenCV rect.width and rect.size().width difference?

Tags: c++, opencv

Sorry for a noob question, but can somebody tell me the difference between this

```
cv:: Rect rect;
int width = rect.width;
int height = rect.height;
```

and this

```
cv::Rect rect;
int width = rect.size().width;
int height = rect.size().height;
```

Comment: There is **NO** difference, other than an extra method being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, **NO difference**.

---

OpenCV is open source, so you can always look at the source code.

You can see that [`width` and `height`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L455) are public member variables:

```
template<typename _Tp> class Rect_
{
public: 
    ...
    _Tp width; //!< width of the rectangle
    _Tp height; //!< height of the rectangle
};
```

and [`size()`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types.hpp#L1884) returns a `cv::Size` initialized with their values:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
Size_<_Tp> Rect_<_Tp>::size() const
{
    return Size_<_Tp>(width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference with respect to the code you have shown.
However, `width` and `height` are **public** attributes of `Rect` and if you change them you will be changing `Rect`.

`size()` just returns the size (width, height) of `Rect`. You cannot change `Rect` through the members of `size()`.